# C# Is it possible to change e.Label value in ListView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have `ListView` where I'm trying to `edit` a row. But also I need to update the `e.Label` in `AfterLabelEdit`. Is there any workaround where I can change the value of `e.Label` in this event. For example, if I have typed 'Zip' and when I hit enter it should become 'Zip1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cancel the edit based on some criteria and assign a new value to text of the item.

The [`Label`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventargs.label(v=vs.110).aspx) contains proposed value for the label, so you can write the criteria based on that. Then to cancel the edit, it's enough to set [`CancelEdit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventargs.canceledit(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the event argument to `true`. Then using its [`Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.labelediteventargs.item(v=vs.110).aspx) property yo ucan find the editing item and set the new label for it.

For example:

```
private void listView1_AfterLabelEdit(object sender, LabelEditEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Label == "something")
    {
        e.CancelEdit = true;
        ((ListView)sender).Items[e.Item].Text = "something else";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you edit the value of a row in a `listview` , like "zip" , to  "zip1" , the value of `e.label` in `AfterLabelEdit` event will be changed automatically after you hit Enter or `listview` leaves focus.You can not assign a value to `e.label` like `e.label="zip1";` and the value of `e.label` won't be anything except "zip1" which is the value after edition.